# Updating WP plugin to trunk or specific version

Tags: wordpress

I’ve greatly re-written my plugin and have revamped an upgrade process. I would like to test if it behaves as I expect it to behave when someone updates to this version.
Therefore, the question is, is it possible to force my development website to show a link to upgrade to trunk or even better specific tag (without changing version in repository) of my plugin so that I can test it?

Answer (score 0):

In case someone needs this as well.
According Samuel Wood (Otto/Otto42) to there is [Plugin Beta Tester](https://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/plugin-beta-tester/trunk/) which lets you download and install trunk version or tag with a higher version (I've tested this one).
Since you don't update readme.txt in trunk, users do not get prompted about new version and repository doesn't get updated either so you can fully test new version of the plugin, from start to end without worry about someone getting it before time.

Comment: Hi @igor-yavych, I know its been long time since this was posted and I saw that the Plugin Beta Tester plugin is discontinued, do you know about a similar plugin which is live now?